# Como eu adiciono um hyperlink na Checkbox em flutter

Tags: flutter, checkbox, dart, link

Bom dia, tudo bem pessoal?
Eu gostaria de adicionar um hyperlink no trecho "política de privacidade", e não estou conseguindo. É possível fazer isso?
Se alguém puder me auxiliar agradeço.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GetCheckValue extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  GetCheckValueState createState() {
    return new GetCheckValueState();
  }
}

class GetCheckValueState extends State<GetCheckValue> {
  bool _isChecked = false;
  String _currText = '';

  List<String> text = [
    "Declaro que li e aceito os termos da Política de Privacidade."

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: text
                .map((t) => CheckboxListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        t,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 17.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      value: _isChecked,
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          _isChecked = val;
                          if (val == true) {
                            _currText = t;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você consegue criar um hyperlink em um texto utilizando `RichText` e `TextSpan`, por exemplo:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Concordo com os ',
        children: <InlineSpan>[
          _buildLink(
            context: context,
            title: 'Termos de uso',
            onTap: () {
              print('Tap termos de uso');
            }
          ),
          const TextSpan(text: ' e a '),
          _buildLink(
            context: context,
            title: 'Política de Privacidade',
            onTap: () {
              print('Tap política de privacidade');
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  TextSpan _buildLink({
    BuildContext context,
    String title,
    VoidCallback onTap,
  }) {
    return TextSpan(
      text: title,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.copyWith(
            fontSize: 14.0,
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = onTap,
    );
  }
```

E dentro de um `TextSpan` utilizar o parâmetro `recognizer` para criar o hyperlink, deixando uma parte do texto como link.

Veja na [prática no DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/a574881c2845c91bfcc3cb506a606055).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso, adapte para o seu caso. Não é necessário um `CheckboxListTile` e sim apenas uma `Row` com um `Checkbox` e o `RichText`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Dessa forma consegui resolver. Algumas coisas no flutter ainda me são obscuras. Ajudou bastante!

Comment: De nada, se ajudou, poderia marcar a resposta como correta. :D

Comment: @SecchiZ marca a resposta como correta aí amigão! Ajude a reputação de quem te ajuda!